FF VII intro question



Would some one explain me what is the meaning of this wril of stars in the start of ffvii intro?
And Aeris is looking at mako leaking from a heater ,why?

Have you beaten the game?

How can there be a fantasy after Final Fantasy I?

In the opening for Final Fantasy VII Remake, the glowing points we see before transitioning to Aeris are sparks created by the flare from a mako reactor.
Mako energy is refined from the Lifestream, the essence of the planet that contains the memories and possibly souls of everyone who ever lived. Aeris is half-Cetra, giving her the ability to commune with and guide the Lifestream. If you listen closely during the whirling sparks part of the intro, there are sounds that could be indistinct voices. So Aeris is probably staring at the mako sparks because she's listening to the fragments of memories and life in them.
There's speculation that she specifically hears Sephiroth starting to corrupt the Lifestream and that's why she's concerned. Some people say they can hear fragments of Sephiroth's theme in the background. In the remake's intro, the music starts with an adapted version of Sephiroth's One-Winged Angel boss theme, which led to this theory.
